# Looking for something like DatePickerDialog but with a recurrence function

Tags: android, calendar, android-datepicker

I'm new to Android development, and I am trying to build an app that has a task list with items that recur at a user specified frequency.  I would like the user to select the first due date for the task, and also specify the frequency for the recurrence, similar to how you can do this for events in Google Calendar (I am currently using a DatePickerDialog to allow the user to select a due date; I am just missing the recurrence piece).  However, I do not want to put events in the calendar using the calendar API.  I have searched StackOverflow and have come up empty; I see plenty on the calendar API but don't believe this is what I am looking for (since I don't want to put anything in the user's calendar); is this a correct assumption?  Is there a class that I have missed that handles recurring dates?  Or, is there a simpler way to go about this?

Comment: You may be looking for this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: @Henry Thanks, I had looked at AlarmManager as well, but don't believe it is exactly what I am looking for.  I want to be able to see if a task is due today when my app opens, so I can display it in the main activity.  For this I believe I need to be able to compare the next occurrence date of a task to the current date, which requires that I be able to set a recurrence.  Is there a way to do this with AlarmManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for pretty much the same thing and I ended up using [BetterPickers](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers) library. There are various dialogs you can use and one of them is also a RecurrencePickerDialog which looks a lot like the one in Google Calendar app.